# Fustenberg´s Example

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, self-learning, ergodic-theory

I´m trying to find a solution for the Excercise 6.2.1 from the book "Foundations of Ergodic Theory", written for Marcelo Viana and Oliviera.

**The Problem:**

Show that if $u$ is a measurable solution of the cohomological equation (6.2.2)$u(x+\alpha)-u(x)=\phi(x)$, then $h :\mathbb{T}^2→\mathbb{T}^2$,$h(x,y)=(x,y+u(x))$ is an ergodic equivalence between $(f_{0},m)$
and $(f ,m)$, that is, $h$ is an invertible measurable transformation that preserves the
measure m and conjugates the two maps $f$ and $f_{0}$. Deduce that $(f ,m) $ cannot be ergodic.

**My Aproach**

The inverse of $h$ obviuosly is the function

$$h^{-1}(x,y)=(x,y-u(x))$$

hence $h$ is invertible. The function $h$ is a conjugation: this is equivalent to the fact that $u$ is a solution of the cohomological equation.

Now, what I'm still can not prove is that $h$ preserves the mesure m. I know from Mañé's books that must be prove using the Fubbini's Theorem: some like the following:

For $E\subset \mathbb{T}^2$:

$$m(h^{-1}(E))=\int_{\mathbb{T}^2}1_{h^{-1}(A)}dm$$
$$=\int_{\mathbb{T}^2}1_{A}(h(x,y))dm$$
$$=\int_{\mathbb{T}^2}1_{A}((x,y+u(x)))dm$$
$$=\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}\left[\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}1_{A}((x,y+u(x)))d\nu(y)\right]d\mu(x)$$
.........
$$=\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}\left[\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}1_{A}((x,y))d\mu(x)\right]d\nu(y)$$
$$=m(E)$$

My question is: How can I (fill the ditails and) complete the proof using Fubbini's Theorem?

Comment: what is equation 6.2.2?

Comment: $u(x+\alpha)-u(x)=\phi(x)$

Comment: Hint: for a differentiable $u$ the Jacobian of $h$ is clearly $1$.